# How to set type "time" with a model and ebean?

Tags: time, ebean

I'd like to only use the time for my model, to define when in the day the event is going to occur, but the only way I found was to do this:

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIME)
public Date end;
```

But I'd like to have in my database, a type TIME which is exactly what I'm looking for.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `java.sql.Time`, but be careful - it has other definition than MySQL TIME column type - it operates only in range `00:00:00` - `23:59:59` (although MySQL allows you to store intervals -/+ 838 hours)

model:

```
public Time end;
```

set with:

```
event.end = Time.valueOf("12:15:00");
```

Anyway maybe it's safer to store the time/interval as a string or integer (of minutes)?

Comment: Which Time object is from ? java.sql.Time ?